# how to create an nginx rewrite to add / to url

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to create an nginx rewrite that will rewrite /pagename to /pagename/

I've tried using:

```
location ~ "^/test$" {
    rewrite /test /test/ break;
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work...

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of a `rewrite` statement is a regular expression, and the flag you should use is probably `permanent` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details), for example:

```
location ~ "^/test$" {
    rewrite ^(/test)$ $1/ permanent;
}
```

But you do not need to match the regular expression twice, once in the `location` and again in the `rewrite`, so a `return` would be more efficient, for example:

```
location ~ "^(/test)$" {
    return 301 $1/$is_args$args;
}
```

Also, the `location` matches a single URI, to the `=` operator would be better than a regular expression (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details). So the preferred solution is:

```
location = /test {
    return 301 $uri/$is_args$args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using return:

```
return 301 /test/;
```